# Running PySimpleGUI on Jupyter

Tags: pysimplegui

How can PySimpleGUI be used on the web (especially Jupyter)? Should PySimpleGUIWeb be used instead? I know it can be run on replit but what I want is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you run it ? What the result and question ?

Comment: @JasonYang Yes. I ran it. It didn't work. PySimpleGUI is for desktop guis. And PySimpleGUIWeb didn't work either. But as I said this second one works on replit

Comment: I know nothing about jupyter. I install it by `pip install notebook` and run by `jupyter notebook` in console, then select `new Python3`. After enter script and run, window shown and work fine. PySimpleGUI is already installed before I installed notebook.

Comment: @JasonYang You run Jupyter offline but I run it on the web. That's the difference.

Comment: @JasonYang Here: https://jupyter.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can use both PySimpleGUIWeb and PySimpleGUI in Jupyter, but your decision depends on your use case.

If you are trying to run the GUI on the computer that is running the code, you can use PySimpleGUI. You'll need to be running the code on an OS with a desktop environment.

If you wish to access the GUI from any other computer, you will want to use PySimpleGUIWeb.

**Example 1:** [Using PySimpleGUI in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c8f7.png)

> ```
> import PySimpleGUI as sg
>
> sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
> # All the stuff inside your window.
> layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
>             [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
>             [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]
>
> # Create the Window
> window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
> # Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
> while True:
>     event, values = window.read()
>     if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
>         break
>     print('You entered ', values[0])
>
> window.close()
> ```

Example code from: https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#jump-start

**Example 2:** [Using PySimpleGUIWeb in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYmjw.png)

> ```
> import PySimpleGUIWeb as sg
>
> layout = [  [sg.Text('My Window')],
>             [sg.Input(key='-IN-'), sg.Text(size=(12,1), key='-OUT-')],
>             [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]
>
> window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, web_port=2222, web_start_browser=False)
>
> while True:             # Event Loop
>     event, values = window.read()
>     print(event, values)
>     if event in (None, 'Exit'):
>         break
>     if event == 'Go':
>         window['-OUT-'].Update(values['-IN-'])
> window.close()
> ```

Example code from: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/2462

When I just did a test PySimpleGuiWeb code, I had an import error pop up using Python 3.9, so I downgraded to Python 3.8.12 and it worked great.

Navigate to http://0.0.0.0:2222/ to view the window when you run the PySimpleGuiWeb version.

You'll obviously need to install PySimpleGUIWeb and PySimpleGUI in your environment for the code to run.

Also, you may need to mess around with firewall rules on your router to access the PySimpleGUIWeb instance from other computers.

Comment: Thanks. I will check your answer. The answer to this question is still interesting to me.